# How do I change the default location of a terminal command?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, anaconda

Consider this command:

```
$~ which python
/home/satyarth934/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I wish to change the default execution file for 'python' to '/home/satyarth934/anaconda2/bin/python'

I have both Anaconda2 and Anaconda3 installed on my machine.

I am unable to find how this can be done.

Comment: It depends on the order of the directories in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Thank you @ceving

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that your target python binary comes first in `PATH`:

```
export PATH=/home/satyarth934/anaconda2/bin/:$PATH
which python
```

Answer (score -2):

To create a symbolic link

```
ln -s /path/to/original/ /path/to/linkName
```

https://www.nixtutor.com/freebsd/understanding-symbolic-links/